# LinqToEntity join int and string checks null

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

We have two tables:

```
TableA : ID (bigint),Title
TableB : ID (bigint),RelatedObjectID (varchar(36)),Title
```

We would like to have an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT a.Title as ATitle,b.Title as BTitle FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON CAST(a.ID as varchar(36))=b.RelatedObjectID
```

Here's how we've written it using Linq:

```
from a in TableA
join b in TableB on a.ID.ToString() equals b.RelatedObjectID
```

And here's what we got  :

```
SELECT a.Title as ATitle,b.Title as BTitle FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON CAST(a.ID as varchar(36))=b.RelatedObjectID OR (a.ID IS NULL AND b.RelatedObjectID IS NULL)
```

Which makes the query very slow when we have large numbers of records on TableA.

I cannot understand what is going on and why it is checking null values.

Comment: As a suggestion i recommend you create a stored procedure for this one, if the performance matter as what you said, then create the exact query you wish to achieve.

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using? If that is EF 6 - try setting `ctx.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;`, where `ctx` is your EF context instance.

Comment: @Valkyriee since it is a query that is built at run time it is not possible for us to create a stored procedure for it.

Comment: Why is `RelatedObjectID` varchar rather than bigint?

Comment: Why aren't you joining on a.ID = b.ID?  You are joining a.ID with b.ReleatedObjectID (which is a varchar936)).

Comment: `since it is a query that is built at run time it is not possible for us to create a stored procedure for it.` Well, you could do it with a sp using parameterised `sp_executesql`. I wouldn't **recommend** it but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Since linq-to-SQL differs from your intended SQL statement, why not just declare the entire statement as a string and run the query against your db via C#?

```
 var strSql = "SELECT a.Title as ATitle,b.Title as BTitle FROM TableA
     a INNER JOIN TableB b ON CAST(a.ID as varchar(36))=b.RelatedObjectID";

 var query = _db.Database.SqlQuery<myModel>(strSql).ToList();
```